# django: how many queries

Tags: django, django-models

a noob question here.

After reading the docs, I found that saving a model with a foreign key reference requires saving a model instance of the object being referenced.

```
a = ModelA.objects.get(pk=1)
b = ModelB(foreignk = a,.....)
b.save()
```

In this case, how many queries are actually executed? If I have the pk of the referenced model, is this the correct method to go ahead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `ForeignKey` field also results in a hidden field having the same name but with `_id` appended. Assigning the foreign PK to that field is enough.

```
b = ModelB(...)
b.foreignk_id = 1
b.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use your solution, you have 2 queries: one for evaluating the queryset for ModelA when you pass it as an argument to ModelB, the second when you call save().

Using Ignacios solution you have just one when saving.